# how to create a count of loads per week on db2?

Tags: sql, count, db2

Hello I am trying to create a count of loads being pulled out from a shipper per week over the last 53 weeks but I am at a total loss!

This is where I am at!

```
SELECT BILL_NUMBER, LEFT(ACTUAL_PICKUP,10) AS ACTUAL_PICKUP FROM TLORDER
WHERE ORIGIN = 'ROCKMURTN'
AND ACTUAL_PICKUP BETWEEN CURRENT TIMESTAMP  - 1 YEAR AND CURRENT TIMESTAMP 
ORDER BY ACTUAL_PICKUp
```

Comment: Is there a `shipper` column in `TLORDER` column? Could you please give couple of rows from `TLORDER` table and your expected output based on that?

Comment: Also do you get any error while running your current query?

Comment: SHIPPER = ORIGIN AND NO ERROR

Comment: Yeah, without structure of table is really hard to tell what options You have. But proper GROUP BY is probably the best of them. :)
Do You have week number in that table?

Comment: Of you are not getting any error, then what is your result? is it not expected?

Comment: i want a count per week of loads being shipped out of this shipper

Comment: I don't have a week number, but these are the columns I am using: actual_pickup, bill_number, and origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not expert in DB2, but quick try in Google lead me to [WEEK_ISO](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005481.html) function.
And Your problem is probably with [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause. You should realy consider trying to understand what it does.
So i think what You want should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    ORIGIN as shipper,
    COUNT(BILL_NUMBER) as count_per_week,
    WEEK_ISO(CREATED_TIME) as week
FROM 
    TLORDER
WHERE 
    ORIGIN = 'ROCKMURTN'
AND CREATED_TIME >= CURRENT TIMESTAMP  - 1 YEAR
GROUP BY
    ORIGIN ,
    WEEK_ISO(CREATED_TIME)
ORDER BY
    ORIGIN ,
    WEEK_ISO(CREATED_TIME)
```

Please, let me know it it helped You.

**[EDIT]**

As pre comment, db2 seems to have [WEEK](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000871.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-182&lang=pl) sunction which counts sunday as start of week.

Comment: Thanks! But how would I have it so that Sunday started as the first day of the week?

Comment: Added edit about WEEK function, this should help You. If my answer have helped You - please mark it as correct.